# loading css file and override the previous one

Tags: javascript, html, css, html5-canvas

I want to load the css properties in javascript.

I have two canvases and i have loaded a css file in the head tag.

I want to do that when a certain option is selected, the css of the canvases change. If it would be simple css it could be done by 'canvas.style.csstext' but i'm applying transform for tilting the element so it doesn't work in 'canvas.style.csstext'.

So how can i do that!

Comment: Can you just save that alternate style in another CSS file with a proper selector and change the `className` of that canvas when needed?

Comment: Yes i have used the different classname! it worked thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, I'll post as an answer here so others can see.

There're various methods, like injecting a `link` element, or use `document.styleSheets[0].insertRule`, but in your case, a better solution would be to include both `CSS` files in header, with different selectors, and modify the `canvas.className` when needed.

Illustration:

```
<link href="main.css" /> <!--canvas{border:...}-->
<link href="alternate.css" /> <!--canvas.alter{border:...}-->
<!--...-->
<canvas id="needToAlter"></canvas>
<button onclick="document.getElementById('needToAlter').className+=' alter';">Alter</button>
```